# NodeJS, Express: How to call backend from frontend using ajax?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I am developing a frontend application as well as a backend API (JSON). Both are in Node/Express. In the frontend, I need to call multiple API's in the backend layer. Since both apps run on different port, AJAx calls cannot be made directly. Therefore, I have 2 options:

1. Frontend AJAX calls a route which initiates an HTTP request to the backend.
2. I allow CORS in the backend and then AJAX can call directly the backend

In option **1**, I found myself creating the same code more and more. Code seems to be redundant and for every AJAX call I have an extra HTTP method in the controller. In option **2**, since I am using the package "password", I am not able to pull many of the session content in the backend ince these are 2 different apps (e.g. in the frontend I can simply say "req.user.username", but I am not to do so in the backend). In addition, the user will be able to see in his developer tools the AJAX requests I am issuing to the backend along with some params, which I don't want to happen.

Do you have any comments on the above or can you guide me with some other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: To handle users request use [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) that makes validation on request phase.

Comment: Just implement CORS in your two servers so you can call both APIs directly.  There's no reason to hand implement a proxy when you control both servers.

Comment: CORS seems the better option, but then how can I make use of the session data available in the frontend? I authenticate users in the frontend, thus saving some valuable info.